# Subsetting Data with GREP

Tags: bash, awk, grep, subset

I have a very large text file (16GB) that I want to subset as fast as possible. 
Here is a sample of the data involved

```
0   M   4   0   
0   0   Q   0   10047345    3080290,4098689 50504886,4217515    9848058,1084315 50534229,4217515    50591618,4217515    26242582,2597528    34623075,3279130    68893581,5149883    50628761,4217517    32262001,3142702    35443881,3339757
0   108 C   0   50628761
0   1080    C   0   50628761
1   M   7   0
1   0   Q   0   17143989    
2   M   15  1   
2   0   Q   0   17143989    4219157,1841361,853923,1720163,1912374,1755325,4454730  65548702,4975721    197782,39086    54375043,4396765    31589696,3091097    6876504,851594  3374640,455375  13274885,1354902    31585771,3091016    61234218,4723345    31583582,3091014
2   27  C   0   31589696
```

The first number on every line is a *sessionID* and any line with an 'M' denotes the start of a session (data is grouped by session). The number following an M is a *Day* and the second number is a *userID*, a user can have multiple sessions.

I want to extract all lines related to a specific user which for each session include all of the lines up until the next 'M' line is encountered (can be any number of lines). As a second task I also want to extract all session lines related to a specific day.

For example with the above data, to extract the records for userid '0' the output would be:

```
0   M   4   0   
0   0   Q   0   10047345    3080290,4098689 50504886,4217515    9848058,1084315 50534229,4217515    50591618,4217515    26242582,2597528    34623075,3279130    68893581,5149883    50628761,4217517    32262001,3142702    35443881,3339757
0   108 C   0   50628761
0   1080    C   0   50628761
1   M   7   0
1   0   Q   0   17143989
```

To extract the records for day 7 the output would be:

```
1   M   7   0
1   0   Q   0   17143989
```

I believe there is a much more elegant and simple solution to what I have achieved so far and it would be great to get some feedback and suggestions. Thank you.

### What I have tried

I tried to use **pcrgrep -M** to apply this pattern directly (matching data between two M's) but struggled to get this working across the linebreaks. I still suspect this may be the fastest option so any guidance on whether this may be possible would be great.

The next part is quite scattered and it is not necessary to read on if you already have an idea for a better solution!

Failing the above, I split the problem into two parts:

- **Part 1:** Isolating all 'M' lines to obtain a list of sessions which belonging to that user/day

  1. grep method is fast (then need to figure out how to use this data)

     `time grep -c "M\t.*\t$user_id" trainSample.txt >> sessions.txt`
  2. awk method to create an array is slow

     `time myarr=$(awk '/M\t.*\t$user_id/ {print $1}' trainSample.txt`
- **Part 2:** Extracting all lines belonging to a session on the list created in part 1

  1. Continuing from the awk method, I ran grep for each but this is WAY too slow (days to complete 16GB)

     ```
     for i in "${!myarr[@]}"; 
     do 
       grep "^${myarr[$i]}\t" trainSample.txt >> sessions.txt
       echo -ne "Session $i\r"
     done
     ```
  2. Instead of running grep once per session ID as above using them all in the one grep command is MUCH faster (I ran it with 8 sessionIDs in a [1|2|3|..|8] format and it took the same time as each did separately i.e. 8X faster). However I need then to figure out how to do this dynamically

#### Update

I have actually established a working solution which only takes seconds to complete but it is some messy and inflexible bash coe which I have yet to extend to the second (isolating by days) case.

Comment: It seems like you are dealing with some sort of flat file, I don't think bash is the right tool for the job here.  I would try loading your data into a database and then querying your data as you wish.

Comment: To make the question perfect, please add what is the expected output for your given input

Comment: @dood The ultimate goal of this is to subset the datafile and then load only the relevant data into a database. Due to the huge size, loading everything into the DB takes much too long. You may be right that bash is not the right tool though I am attracted to the speed of grep against other methods (I tried with a python script too)

Comment: @fedorqui I have edited the question now, hope that is clearer.

Comment: Can "Day"s repeat? I mean can you have entries for day 7 then entries for day 15 and then other entries for day 7 again?

Comment: @EdMorton Yes days can repeat, the data is grouped by users rather than by day so the data relevant to one day is scattered throughout. Multiple sessions can occur on the same day for the same user and most of the users will have data for each day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I want to extract all lines related to a specific user which for each session include all of the lines up until the next 'M' line is encountered (can be any number of lines).

```
$ awk '$2=="M"{p=$4==0}p' file
0   M   4   0   
0   0   Q   0   10047345    3080290,4098689 50504886,4217515    9848058,1084315 50534229,4217515    50591618,4217515    26242582,2597528    34623075,3279130    68893581,5149883    50628761,4217517    32262001,3142702    35443881,3339757
0   108 C   0   50628761
0   1080    C   0   50628761
1   M   7   0
1   0   Q   0   17143989
```

> As a second task I also want to extract all session lines related to a specific day.

```
$ awk '$2=="M"{p=$3==7}p' file
1   M   7   0
1   0   Q   0   17143989
```

Comment: This is a great solution, thank you! 

Running these on a 1/41 chunk of the data takes 20s each which assuming it scales linearly works out at roughly **14 mins**, which I think is quite reasonable.

If anyone has any speed enhancements however I would be happy to hear them.

Comment: Interesting solution, well done! Maybe instead of `p` you could use something with a name that makes its point more relevant: `switch`, `flag` or something like this. Also, `awk -v id=0 '$2="M"{flag=$4=id}flag' file` will allow to provide the id as a variable.

Comment: @user2071737, similar `perl` solution would be `perl -ae '$p = $F[3] == 0 if $F[1] eq "M"; print if $p' file` and `perl -ae '$p = $F[2] == 7 if $F[1] eq "M"; print if $p' file` respectively.. can you check how that fares?

Comment: If days cannot repeat then for efficiency you could `exit` when `p` changes from true to false in the second script.

Comment: @Sundeep Have you tested this code? It doesn't produce any output when I run it as is. I will not have a chance to debug until after this weekend but will try it again then.

Comment: @user2071737, probably because options should've been `-ane` instead of `-ae` (which works with perl version 5.20 and above only).. either way, I do not think `perl` would be any faster and most likely slow compared to this `awk` solution

Comment: @Sundeep that was the issue alright, I ran that a few times and got an average around 25s for part one and 32s for part two so it is slower than the awk alternative